Refresh Token cannot be written into the browser's cookies
I encountered a strange situation. My project uses an HTTP-only refresh token. After the user successfully completes the login verification, the backend sends an HTTP-only refresh token to the frontend.
I can see the refresh token in response header
When I use my home computer and enter the website using the Chrome browser, I can see the HTTP-only cookie returned in the response headers in the browser’s developer tools.
However, I can't see this cookie in the application’s cookies, which results in the user having to log in again to get the refresh token every time they visit the website.
I can't see the cookies in my browser
However, when I perform the same operation on my company’s computer, I can see the HTTP-only cookie returned in the response headers in the browser’s developer tools, and I can also see this cookie in the application’s cookies.
I can see the refresh token
And the browser can see the cookie as well
Why is this happening?
This is my code
I have tried using the Edge browser and encountered the same issue. However, when I perform the same operation on my Xiaomi tablet, the problem does not occur.

Try the ways of

Your browsers might be blocking certain types of cookies, especially if they’re third-party or not secure.


For Chrome, you need to set SameSite=None and Secure directives on the cookie. If not set, it might cause visibility issues.


If using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS), you need to set the withCredentials flag when making the request. The server should return the header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true. You can’t use wildcards on a request that uses credentials.


The visibility of the cookie can be affected by the path and domain for which the cookie is set. If they don’t match the current page, the cookie won’t be visible.

